# Show image from sql on non javascript link

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, html, image

Hi say of have a table of cars in my SQL database. That table has a column for the car make and a column called picture of type:

```
Picture(image, null)
```

I'm then displaying my cars in a repeater and so it might look like this:

```
<asp:Repeater id="carsRepeater" runat="server" DataSourceID="CarsDataSource>
  <HeaderTemplate>
    <table>
  </HeaderTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <asp:Label id="carMakeLabel" runat="Server" Text='<%# Eval("Make") %>' />
      </td>
      <td>
        Some how display a clickable image here
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <FooterTemplate>
    </table>
  </Footer>
</asp:Repeater>
```

What I'm wanting is in column two to get the picture of the car to display and make it so you can click on that picture and it will run a method in the code behind. Also I have this requirement where the picture click method mustn't require javascript to run.

Can someone please give me an idea of how I would go about this?

I'm currently thinking about putting the image somehow in a link but I'm not sure how to display the image. Maybe the `asp:Image` but that requires an `ImageUrl`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write an HTTPHandler (say CarImage.ashx) and in that handler, given ID of the image return the binary data with ContentType of image/gif (or whatever). Render an image tag in the datagrid with src as CarImage.ashx?ImageID=xxxxx. The process is described many place including [this one](http://www.codeforasp.net/tag/retrieve-images-in-gridview-using-image-datatype).

Answer (score 1):

Try image button, it displays an image, doesn't require javascript and you can run a method on click event from code behind

Comment: Thanks, but I'm unsure how to set the image to this button given it's not coming from a file location but from sql.